# Python getattr with joblib Parallel

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, joblib, python-class

I have two classes, the first one is my base implementation, and the second class uses the class one and calls its methods using joblib's Parallel so that it would be something like this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, param_list: list):
        self.param_list = param_list

    def method1(self, w, z):
        pass

    def method2(self, w, y, z):
        pass
```

Now, the second class is implemented like this:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

class MyParallelClass:
    def __init__(self, param_list: list[dict]):
        self.param_list = param_list

    def method1(self, x: list[dict]):
        results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(MyClass(**params).method1)(**arguments)
                                      for params in self.param_list
                                      for arguments in x)
        return results

    def method2(self, x: list[dict]):
        results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(MyClass(**params).method2)(**arguments)
                                      for params in self.param_list
                                      for arguments in x)
        return results
```

This works, but as you can see, `MyParallelClass` methods 1 and 2 are essentially the same, the only thing that changes is the method is called from `MyClass`

So I'd like to simplify this having an internal method that handles the parallel execution, given a parameter that tells me which method to execute, so it would be something like this:

```py
class MyParallelClass:
    def __init__(self, param_list: list[dict]):
        self.param_list = param_list

    def method1(self, x: list[dict]):
        return self._run(x, method="method1")

    def method2(self, x: list[dict]):
        return self._run(x, method="method2")
    
    def _run(self, x, method):
        pass
```

How can I write this `_run` method? I tried using the standard `getatrr` like this, but failed:

```py
def _run(self, x: list[dict], method):
    results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(getattr(MyClass(**params), method))(**arguments)
                                  for params in self.param_list
                                  for arguments in x)
    return results
```

but I get this error:

```py
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this example explain you how to reuse class methods?

```py
class Base:

  def __init__(self, init_arg):
    self.init_arg = init_arg

  def method1(self, x):
    print(x, "from method1,", "iteration_number is", self.init_arg)
    return f"lower value is {x.lower()} [iteration number is {self.init_arg}]"

  def method2(self, x, y):
    print(x, y, "from method2,", "iteration_number is", self.init_arg)
    return f"lower values are {x.lower()}, {y.lower()} [iteration number is {self.init_arg}]"

class Executor:

  def __init__(self, init_arg):
    self.base_instance = Base(init_arg)

  def _method_base(self, method_name, *args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(self.base_instance, method_name)(*args, **kwargs)

  def method1(self, x):
    return self._method_base('method1', x)

  # here x is *args and y=y is **kwargs
  def method2(self, x, y):
    return self._method_base('method2', x, y=y)

for idx, val in enumerate([("X1", "Y1"), ("X2", "Y2"), ("X3", "Y3")]):
  executor = Executor(idx)
  _1 = executor.method1(val[0])
  _2 = executor.method2(val[0], val[1])
  print("calculated values: ", _1, _2)
```

Output:

```
X1 from method1, iteration_number is 0
X1 Y1 from method2, iteration_number is 0
calculated values:  lower value is x1 [iteration number is 0] lower values are x1, y1 [iteration number is 0]
X2 from method1, iteration_number is 1
X2 Y2 from method2, iteration_number is 1
calculated values:  lower value is x2 [iteration number is 1] lower values are x2, y2 [iteration number is 1]
X3 from method1, iteration_number is 2
X3 Y3 from method2, iteration_number is 2
calculated values:  lower value is x3 [iteration number is 2] lower values are x3, y3 [iteration number is 2]
```

Comment: In this case, it's basically what you have, only that X and y are both a list of dicts, but that should change anything. But what is important, is that what you call the Base class, has parameters as well, so you need to __init__ that class, the issue I have, is that I need to use method 1/2 but after the class instance is initialized, and I cant do it outside the for loop, because the init parameters changes in each loop

Comment: @RodrigoA I didn't plan to write exact code for you and provided just core of idea. But okay, I added example how to use `__init__` inside loop. Is this answer to `But what is important, is that what you call the Base class, has parameters as well, so you need to init that class, the issue I have, is that I need to use method 1/2 but after the class instance is initialized, and I cant do it outside the for loop`?

Comment: Thanks! I might didn't explain myself correctly, the initialization is inside the joblib Parallel loop, which is a bit different of a regular loop